# Transaction cost in a truffle test

Tags: truffle, testing

I've a contract under test and the method I'm checking is supposed to transfer an amount, and in order to check I need to have the cost of the transaction.
I'm using this code:

```
var tx = await instance.withdraw(web3.toWei(25,"finney"));
  console.log(tx);
  let ownerBalanceAfter = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);
assert.equal(ownerBalanceAfter-ownerBalance,web3.toWei(25,"finney")-web3.eth.gasPrice.mul(tx.receipt.gasUsed)); //withdraw done
```

The test fails with some unexpected small difference, even if I apparently try to compute the gas cost. 
Internally the method call transfer(address), that I know it consumes other gas, but shouldn't this be counted in the `tx.receipt.gasUsed`?
So what is wrong in my balance computation?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can specify the GasPrice for the transaction and this ensure me on what is used, so I just changed:

```
var tx = await instance.withdraw(web3.toWei(25,"finney"),{gasPrice:web3.eth.gasPrice});
```

adding gasPrice as argument, and test now works.